# Verb tense agreement - spring back

Tags: word-choice, tense-agreement

**Example sentence**:

> The material can be squeezed and stuffed into any shape, and still *sprung back* to
> its original form.

Is *sprung back* correctly used in the sentence? Should it be *spring back*?

What I understand about past participle is a verb to describe an action that has already completed. Present tense is expressing an action that is currently going on or habitually performed, or a state that currently or generally exists.

The ability for the material to spring back to its original form is a fact and reproducible action. The beginning of the sentence uses *can be squeezed*, is it correct to use *sprung back* here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree it is probably wrong.

When manual intervention is required, a verb could be used in its past participle form, for example:

> The part can be unscrewed, and then *screwed* back into place.

However, in your example, it sounds like the material will naturally 'spring' back into shape by itself. Unlike my example, where the reader may be doing both the screwing and unscrewing, the person in your example who squeezes and stuffs the material will not do any 'springing'. I think it should say:

> The material can be squeezed and stuffed into any shape, and **will spring** back to its original form.